# Shell script works when run manually but does not when run at docker container startup

Tags: bash, docker, synology

I installed Docker on a Synology NAS.
I created a container that runs an Ubuntu instance that runs a website server.

To launch my service (named "dodoc"), I use npm and pm2.

So when my container starts, I have to manually open the container terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd /home
pm2 start dodoc
pm2 startup
```

And then, it works perfectly.

The problem is that I would like to launch the service automatically at container startup. Usually, a `pm2 save` should do it. But on a Synology NAS it does not work, don't know why.

So... I tried a different approach:
using a shell script as a CMD on my container.

My container CMD line is:

> /bin/bash -c /root/Documents/startupCommands.sh

Like this, my container does run my script at startup, but the script does not work, whereas it works if I run it manually through the terminal.

The script (named "startupCommands.sh"):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home && pm2 start dodoc
cd /home && pm2 startup

/bin/bash
```

On a NAS Synology, we have to set a directory on the NAS where the container will have access.
This directory where I can put my script file is at `/root/Documents` in the container terminal.
But my service is to be run from `/home`.
Why did I put my script in a different directory? Because on a Synology NAS, you have to set the CMD line at container creation and can't modify it after. So if you try to run a `script.sh` that does not exist yet, the container will keep rebooting indefinitely. So you have to put the script file in a directory you have access to without using the container terminal.

Well... if I manually do the following command in the Terminal, it works:

```
root@ubuntu-dodoc10:/home# /root/Documents/startupCommands.sh
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /home/dodoc in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

But if I take a look at the container log, this is what happens at startup:

```
]0;root@ubuntu-dodoc10: /homeroot@ubuntu-dodoc10:/home# 
/root/Documents/startupCommands.sh: line 4: pm2: command not found
/root/Documents/startupCommands.sh: line 5: pm2: command not found
```

And obviously, the server does not start...

I've tried:

1. to install `npm` in the root directory
2. to use `(cd /home && pm2 start dodoc)` commands in the script
3. to create another script in the `/home` directory and run it from the first script

Nothing worked.

`Dockerfile`:

```
{
   "CapAdd" : null,
   "CapDrop" : null,
   "cmd" : "/bin/bash -c /root/Documents/startupCommands.sh",
   "cpu_priority" : 50,
   "enable_publish_all_ports" : false,
   "enable_restart_policy" : true,
   "enable_service_portal" : null,
   "enabled" : true,
   "env_variables" : [
      {
         "key" : "PATH",
         "value" : "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
      }
   ],
   "exporting" : false,
   "id" : "4fc2468eaf2a84c57ddb25f1818cdef6650a792d67ac6ad7d5d69e8fd470f8c0",
   "image" : "ubuntu:latest",
   "is_ddsm" : false,
   "is_package" : false,
   "links" : [],
   "memory_limit" : 1073741824,
   "name" : "ubuntu-dodoc-test",
   "network" : [
      {
         "driver" : "host",
         "name" : "host"
      }
   ],
   "network_mode" : "host",
   "port_bindings" : [],
   "privileged" : false,
   "shortcut" : {
      "enable_shortcut" : false,
      "enable_status_page" : false,
      "enable_web_page" : false,
      "web_page_url" : ""
   },
   "use_host_network" : true,
   "volume_bindings" : [
      {
         "host_volume_file" : "/docker/dodoc",
         "mount_point" : "/root/Documents",
         "type" : "rw"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: `/bin/bash -c /root/Documents/startupCommands.sh` tries to run `/root/Documents/startupCommands.sh` directly as a command (like `ls`, or `grep`), but you want to point Bash to a script to run: `/bin/bash /root/Documents/startupCommands.sh` should do that.

Comment: Then again, your errors logs indicate that the script actually runs... can you show more of your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yep, I know that the script runs. The problem is that when I run it manually it works, but when it's the container that runs it... it doesn't work. - I've tried as you said, without the -c, it does not change anything ... :'(

Comment: What you added isn't the Dockerfile. It's usually called just `Dockerfile`, and starts with a `FROM` line; it's not JSON formatted.

Comment: There is no Dockerfile available when using the Docker Synology Package. The only file available for configuration is the one I added in the end. Sorry

Comment: That's not a valid `Dockerfile`; could you share the actual `Dockerfile` you used, and/or correct the information about where this JSON data comes from? A `Dockerfile` uses a completely different syntax (which you already allude to where you describe the `CMD` directive you are using in your actual Dockerfile`).

Comment: Sounds like your interactive shell has commands to enable nvm in its `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or other dotfiles, but you haven't put those same commands in your script.

Answer (score 1):

`pm2: command not found`. That seems pretty clear.

If a command is not found, then the next steps are:

- Is `pm2` available in the container?
- Is its directory in the `PATH`?
- What happens if you specify the full path?

You can put some debug statements in your script, like

```
cd /home
echo -n 'cd-ed to '
pwd
echo -n "Trying to execute pm2:"
which pm2
echo $PATH
pm2 start dodoc
pm2 startup
```

to help you answer the questions in the list above.

If you're faced with `command not found` as error message, you can also put the full name of the executable in the script:

```
cd /home
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/pm2/pm2 start dodoc
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/pm2/pm2 startup
```

Note that the commands in the script may also require certain `PATH` settings. You may need add those directories to the `PATH` as well.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The problem with comments is, that it does not allow this size and formatting of the code. I'll clean-up after the answer is found. Promise.